# Is it necessary to do multiple hypothesis testing for AUC comparison?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, concordance

Dear all: Is it necessary to do multiple hypothesis testing for AUC comparison. For example, if I calculate AUC from logistic regression, there is an AUC value. As we know, we can compare two models using delong teat for AUC. Is it necessary to do multiple hypothesis testing for this kimd of comparison? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If there is no hypothesis, then you shouldn't do hypothesis testing.